# Is there a word or phrase for 'shared accountability that leads to collective inaction'?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

When a group as opposed to an individual is responsible for a job or task, and as a result the task does not get performed because everyone assumes that someone else will do it.

Is there a word or phrase to describe this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The term I've heard in the workplace is *[diffusion of responsibility](http://meatballwiki.org/wiki/DiffusionOfResponsibility)*:

> **Diffusion of responsibility** is a tendency of individuals in large
>   groups to avoid taking action to correct a problem because they assume
>   someone else will.

Answer (score 9):

The proverb I've heard for this is *everybody's business is nobody's business*. See [here](http://www.englishproverbs.org/wise-words/everybodybusiness.html) for more.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently [not as common as I'd thought](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dissipated%20responsibility&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) (less than 100 written instances using it as a noun phrase), the first term that came to mind was **dissipated responsibility**.

Comment: _Dissipated responsibility_ sounds like me after a drink or three.

Comment: I did check [thefreedictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dissipated) when I posted this. Before that I'd never known their first definition... *1 - Intemperate in the pursuit of pleasure; dissolute. 2 - Wasted or squandered. 3 - Irreversibly lost [energy].* To be honest, I always assumed *dissipated heat* was simply heat spread out so it wasn't in a single hot spot that might burn you. I'd never thought of it in terms of "irretrievably lost heat". But I guess for me the boozy associations were already colonised by *dissolute*.

Answer (score 2):

This is a form of [diffusion of responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion_of_responsibility).

Answer (score 2):

Inertia of the masses.

BTW that gets 1.26M hits on Google as an exact phrase - thanks to the wry physics reference methinks.

Comment: Physics as in "a crowd at rest tends to stay in the pub"?

Comment: Surely "a mass of people at rest ..." or does that make me a pendant?